# Using a power expansion to find the n-th power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series, matrix-equations

Given that

$\sum_{n}^{\infty} \mu^{n} M^{n} = (I-\mu M)^{-1}$

Wherein $\mu$ is a scalar, $M$ is a matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix of the same dimension as $M$. How do I use this to find the n-th power of the matrix $M$?

The exercise states

*Conclude that $M^{n}$ can be obtained as the coefficient of $\mu^{n}$ in the power expansion of $(I-\mu M)^{-1}$.*

But what are the arguments for this conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing convergence,
$$
(I-\mu M)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}M^{n} =
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}M^{n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu^{n+1}M^{n+1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}M^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{n}M^{n} = I.
$$
As I know, the formula isn't terribly useful for calculating $M^n$ in the practice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd found that, but isn't that just proving the sum converges as given? I assumed that _obtaining $M^{n}$ as the coefficient of $\mu^{n}$_ meant that this was useful to find the n-th power of M -- was I wrong?

Comment: Totally wrong. In fact the formula is useful for approximating matrices of the form $I+$ small matrix (the sum converges when $|\mu|\|M\|<1$).

Comment: But then I don't get the meaning of that sentence. Can you explain what the relevance of the word "coefficient" in the exercise is?

Comment: @LaGuerta, is simply saying the same that the formula with words.

Comment: See, the problem with that is that proving it was the previous exercise, haha. In the formula an expression for the sum is obtained, not $M^{n}$. English is not my native tongue, this may impart my understanding.